# How do I attach a function to an alternative package in R?

Tags: r, julia

I am trying to pass a Julia object into an r environment and am using a method found in the pdf when the following code is entered into R - `RShowDoc("Chapter_XRJulia", package = "XRJulia")` .

> In both R and Julia you need to import the generic
>   function asRObject() or toR() into the application package in order to define
>   methods for it.

It looks like there is a XRjulia.jl file in the XRJulia package the contains the toR() function but I am having trouble trying to import it into the R environment.

This is the code I am currently attempting:

```
library(XRJulia)

#' @description Includes toR() 
#' @import methods
#' @importFrom XRJ\ulia 
#' @importMethodsFrom XRJulia toR 


devtools::document()
```

But this results in the error: Error: Could not find package root.

When I enter `search()`, the package appears, making me think that the path works.

Comment: So you are developing an R package? If you are not developing R packages, you shouldn't use `devtools`, if you are developing R packages, maybe you should use Rstudio and start an R package as a new project.

Comment: And the R side should use `XR::asRObject`, the Julia side should use `toR()`. You don't need to import `toR` into R, it's a Julia thing and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help! No, I am not developing a package but using `devtools` was one of the few suggestions I found online on this topic. Trying `XR::asRObject(juliaGet(dfx), "JuliaInterface")` worked more or less. I got what seems like a 3-d array output in R but was looking for a 2-d dataframe (dfx is a small dataframe imported from a csv and sent to julia from R using juliaEval()). I feel like I need to add `toR()` or `XR::toR()` to the code , but I keep getting, "Error: 'toR' is not an exported object from 'namespace:XR'". Any suggestions?

Comment: I kind of get what you want to do. So basically, you have to find a way in R to transform the 3-d array into the dataframe you want. `XR::asRObject` and `XRJulia` provide the framework but don't provide you with the actual code. Can you provide more detail, like what you get and what you want, and some example code to try on?

Comment: So in trying to create a reproducible example, I think I solved the problem. I was using readTable() from Julia package DataFrames to import the data. This was creating a format that R could not read. By converting the dataframe to a matrix while in Julia before bringing it to R seemed to solve the issue. `ev<-RJulia()`, `ev$Command("df = df[:,:]")` Once in R, I could put it back into a R data frame.